# Is there a way to insert the name of the user who used a template?

Tags: mediawiki, markup

I want to make a template which automatically adds the name of person who used it in another page.

For example if I had the following template named "addedby":

```
Added by '~~~~'.
```

I want it so when I use it in the page like this:

```
This page was {{addedby}}
```

The ~~~~ is automatically replaced by the name of the user who used the template.
For example if user 'john' used the template the final page above would look like this:

```
This page was Added by 'john'.
```

Is this possible? I tried using [~~~~](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Wiki_markup#Signing_comments) but when I save the template ~~~~ is replaced directly in the template when I save it, not when I use the template in any of the pages.

Comment: `This page was {{addedby|~~~~}}`

Comment: The main reason I want this is to be parameter-free. But I guess there's no way without it, or is there?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible in a un[substituted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Substitution) template. You could use the [`{{REVISIONUSER}}` magic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Other_variables_by_type), but it always shows the user who made the last edit to the page not the one who added the template. You must in some way put the user name inside the page markup.

So you can either use a parameter to your template:

```
Added by '{{{1}}}'.
```

```
This page was {{addedby|~~~}}
```

or you use substitution and the [trick from Template:4~](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:4~) for inserting the username:

```
Added by '~~<noinclude></noinclude>~'.
```

```
This page was {{subst:addedby}}
```

(you can also make [show a warning when used without `subst:`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Substitution#Making_templates_behave_differently_when_transcluded_or_substituted))

Comment: A good way to think about this is that the name of the user has to be stored *somewhere*. The fact that it's stored in the page history is no help as using that would mean the revision id had to be stored somewhere - the same problem. So unless you use `subst` (in which case you have some control over what gets written in the article wikitext, and can make it so the username gets written into it) or the name does not get stored in any place that's available to the wikitext parser.

Comment: Note that `~~~` is the signature, not the name. For the name, you can use `{{{subst:REVISIONUSER}}}` probably, at the cost of weird preview behavior.

Comment: @Tgr Right, I just used the signature because the OP had it in his question as well

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a particular extension for that currently. The closest to that I can recommend is https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:LastModified